# Ninject 3.0.0 and NServiceBus 3.3.0 Injection Issue

Tags: wcf, ninject, nservicebus

I have a small testsystem developed to get to know NServiceBus. The classes in the testproject are taken from a production system which uses Castle.Windsor for dependency injection.

In addition to the Ninject and NServiceBus assemblies the testproject is also referencing:

```
Ninject.Extensions.ContextPreservation 3.0.0.0
Ninject.Extensions.Conventions 3.0.0.0
Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope 3.0.0.0
Ninject.Extensions.Wcf 3.0.0.0
Ninject.Web.Common 3.0.0.0
NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.Ninject 3.3.0.0
```

This is the NServiceBus Endpoint configuration:

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server, IWantCustomInitialization
{
    private IKernel _kernel;

    public void Init()
    {
        _kernel = new StandardKernel(new EndpointModule());
        Configure.With()
                 .NinjectBuilder(_kernel)
                 .Log4Net()
                 .XmlSerializer();
    }
}
```

EndpointModule is defined as:

```
public class EndpointModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly().SelectAllTypes().InheritedFrom<IWcfGatewayService>().BindToSelf().Configure(c => c.InTransientScope()));
    }
}
```

Here's an example of a type implementing IWcfGatewayService:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public abstract class WcfGatewayService<TCommand> : IWcfGatewayService where TCommand : ICommand
{
    public IBus Bus { get; set; }

    public ResponseCode Process(TCommand command)
    {
        try
        {
            Bus.SendLocal(command);
            return ResponseCode.Sent;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return ResponseCode.Failed;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the implementation of an actual service:

```
public class PlaceOrderCommandService : WcfGatewayService<PlaceOrderCommand>, IPlaceOrderCommandService
{}
```

and

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPlaceOrderCommandService
{
    [OperationContract(Action = "http://tempuri.org/IPlaceOrderCommandService/Process", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/IPlaceOrderCommandService/ProcessResponse")]
    ResponseCode Process(PlaceOrderCommand command);
}
```

Here's the bootstrapper:

```
public class WcfServiceBootstrapper : IWantToRunAtStartup
{
    private readonly List<ServiceHostBase> _hosts = new List<ServiceHostBase>();

    public void Run()
    {
        var serviceTypes = GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(IWcfGatewayService).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsAbstract && !t.IsInterface).ToList();
        foreach (var host in from serviceType in serviceTypes let baseAddress = new[] { new Uri(string.Format("http://localhost:8778/omjykonservices/{0}", serviceType.Name)) } select new ServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddress))
        {
            _hosts.Add(host);
            var serviceMetadataBehaviour = new ServiceMetadataBehavior
                {
                    HttpGetEnabled = true,
                    MetadataExporter = {PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15}
                };
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceMetadataBehaviour);
            host.Open();
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        foreach (var host in _hosts.Where(host => host != null))
        {
            host.Close();
        }
        _hosts.Clear();
    }
}
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that when the Process method (in WcfGatewayService) is called it fails because the Bus property is null, i.e. no instance of IBus has been injected. However, the documentation for NinjectBuilder (NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.Ninject) clearly states that a call to NinjectBuilder will register an instance of IBus with the IoC, i.e. Ninject. Since this doesn't seem to be the case, I suspect that I must have overlooked something.

Has anyone out there got any experience with this kind of setup? Any suggestions as to why the Bus property doesn't get an instance of IBus injected?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you aren't using Windsor for the container for NServiceBus since (as you stated) everything else is already using it.

Comment: The reason for that is that I've been using Ninject in quite a few other projects and quite frankly I like it a lot, so I decided to use it in connection with experimenting with NServiceBus, which I also happen to like :-) We could talk (face-to-face) about this e.g. tomorrow if you like ;-)

Comment: Could you quickly try out constructor injection? Does it work or ghrow an activation exception?

Comment: Daniel, Ruben, thanks for your answers. I've edited the original post because I've left out an important part which I believe prevents the constructor injection.

Comment: Class WcfServiceBootstrapper

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not using Ninject.Extension.WCF to create your service hosts. You can verify this by adding your own custom dependency and declare as a property. Even with an InjectAttribute it will always be null because your are instantiating the service host yourself and just register the service type. In order to get ninject magic working you need to create the host with the mechanisms provided by the Ninject.Extension.WCF. For example see:

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.wcf/blob/master/src/Examples/WindowsTimeService/WindowsTimeService.cs

```
  var yourServiceConfiguration = NinjectWcfConfiguration.Create<YourService, NinjectServiceSelfHostFactory>();

  var selfHost = new NinjectSelfHostBootstrapper(
            kernel, 
            yourServiceConfiguration );
  selfHost.Start();
```

You can then stop it when the bus is shut down. Ruben was right in his answer normally when using property injection with ninject you have to declare the InjecAttribute on the property. But the ninject object builder for nservicebus has a special heuristics which allows to do property injection without having to declare the inject attribute. This was added as convenience because most of the NSB samples use property injection without any custom container declarations. We thought that must be supported also for Ninject together with NSB.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. The reason I short circuited Ninject was that the version of the Wcf extensions I have only supports http which throws an exception at run time when hosted by NServiceBus as in this example app. So I missed the fact that there is a SelfHosting option for Wcf in Ninject. Is it released on Nuget? Anyhow, thanks for being patient. I'll try things out this evening.

Comment: Daniel, wouldn't my current set up require an additional Create method on the NinjectWcfConfiguration, e.g. Create<NinjectServiceSelfHostFactory>(System.Type serviceType)? Or am I missing something again?

Comment: @norgie Daniel has expanded on this:- http://www.planetgeek.ch/2013/05/07/ninject-with-nservicebus-confusions/

Answer (score 0):

While you have a `Bus` property on the command, it doesnt have an [Inject] attribute on it. OOTB Ninject doesnt inject into properties without such a marking (but Windsor does (from my rough memory of reading the chapter on it in http://manning.com/seemann (which is required reading)))

---

If this isn't the problem, you'll find some good old fashioned debugging is going to beat SO or mailing lists every time:-

To diagnose whether Ninject is actually being used to create the Service, it'd be a good idea to add a ctor and stick a breakpoint on it and see if the caller is Ninject. Another way of achieving the same thing is to implement `IActivation` (or is it called IStart).  Or add an `OnActivation` clause to your `Configure`.

Comment: I've already tried using [Inject] on the Bus property to no avail.

Comment: Ruben, Daniel. Could it be that the way the ServiceHosts gets created in WcfServiceBootstrapper has something to do with the issue?

Comment: @norgie I know if Ninject is doing the creation and the property has an `[Inject]`, it should Just Work. If you have a .svc file per service, you need to point it to the Ninject Factory class to make this happen. If not, you need to find out who is doing the `new` and talk to that about making sure it asks the DI container to do it.

Comment: Hy ruben, this time you are not right. The ninject builder has a special heuristics registered which does not need the inject attribute

Comment: @DanielMarbach Cool - I'm used to that :) Now all we need to know is why/if Ninject [is getting to shoot the bear](http://www.naute.com/jokes/bear.phtml) (Ref my factory in the .svc file point)